# Magento 1.4 url rewrites in multi store environment

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, magento-1.4

Long story short - I'm trying to restore my ver1.4 store (multi-store) but am doing so to a test environment first. (Production has one site working and I don't want to lose it entirely.)

On my test environment, I continue to get the following error message when I try to reindex the Catalog URL Rewrites:

```
    An error occurred while saving the URL rewrite.
```

Before doing that, I had emptied the core_url_rewrites table in the database, cleared the var/cache, var/locks and var/session folders and cleared my browser cache.

I've done it repeatedly to see if I could figure out what was going on. I had read that there was often a problem with url rewrites in multi-store setups when products were in more than one root category. I had a lot of those, so I went through my cata.logs and products and limited each product to just one root category (store/domain.)

My configuration settings are as follows:

```
System -> Configuration -> Web
  URL Options
Add Store Code to Urls  No [GLOBAL] 
Redirect to Base URL if requested URL doesn't match it  No [GLOBAL] 
  Search Engines Optimization
Use Web Server Rewrites  Yes [STORE VIEW] (all store views set to use Website)

System -> Configuration -> Catalog
  Frontend
Use Flat Catalog Category No [GLOBAL]   
Use Flat Catalog Product No [GLOBAL]    
Allow Dynamic Media URLs in Products and Categories  Yes [STORE VIEW]
  Search Engine Optimizations
Autogenerated Site Map  Enable [STORE VIEW] 
Popular Search Terms Enable [STORE VIEW]    
Product URL Suffix .html [STORE VIEW]   
Category URL Suffix .html [STORE VIEW]  
Use Categories Path for Product URLs Yes [STORE VIEW]   
Create Permanent Redirect for old URLs if Url key changed yes [STORE VIEW]  
Page Title Separator - [STORE VIEW] 
Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories No [STORE VIEW]  
Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products No [STORE VIEW]
```

I confirmed that I have the proper .htaccess file in each of my directories (the root and each of the folders with symlinks denoting the various stores/domains.) I also double-checked my index.php files.

Each time I run the Reindexing, it indexes one more item. I have over 2500 items so am inclined to not want to go through it 2500 times. I feel I must be missing something, but I can't figure out what it is.

When I add a new product, it usually gives me an error message that it failed because it couldn't create a url rewrite, but the item is added. Then the next time I reindex, the new item is indexed for all four stores.

This didn't seem to be a problem with my previous setup so it might simply be the goofy way that my test environment is set up.

If anyone has any ideas of how I might identify and/or fix the problem, I'd be MOST appreciative!

Cheers!
Penny

Answer (score 0):

Need more information about the error message. Look in the var/log folder or var/report folder for further information on the exact error and hopefully there is something there that will shed some light. Could be due to a variety of reasons so detailed message is required.

Comment: 2012-11-27T21:37:25+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: filemtime() [  ]: stat failed for /home/../skin/frontend/base/default/js/glider.js in /home/../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php on line 631 
    2012-11-27T21:37:25+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: filemtime() [  ]: stat failed for /home/.../skin/frontend/base/default/js/slider.js in /home/../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php on line 631 
    2012-11-27T21:37:25+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: filemtime() [  ]: stat failed for /home/../skin/frontend/base/default/js/productInfo.js in /home/../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php on line 631

Comment: code snippet follows:
            $shouldMerge = $mustMerge || !$targetFile;
            if (!$shouldMerge) {
                if (!file_exists($targetFile)) {
                    $shouldMerge = true;
                } else {
                    $targetMtime = filemtime($targetFile);
                    foreach ($srcFiles as $file) {
 (line 631)              if (filemtime($file) > $targetMtime) {
                            $shouldMerge = true;
                            break;